# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'PaymentViewModel' of 'function result' Error on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to call a model after I click the pay button, I get this error

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'PaymentViewModel' of 'function result".
```

Check my code below and please correct me where I am getting it wrong.

This is my Payment Form Page

```
class PayfastPayment extends StatefulWidget {
  PayfastPayment({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PayfastPaymentState createState() => _PayfastPaymentState();
}

class _PayfastPaymentState extends State<PayfastPayment> {
  TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController itemNameController = TextEditingController();
  late PaymentViewModel model;
  var client = http.Client();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(centerTitle: true, title: const Text("Payment Page")),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: amountController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Amount',
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: itemNameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Item Name',
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 220,
            height: 100,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                print(
                    "Amount: ${amountController.text} Item: ${itemNameController.text}");
                model.payment(amountController.text, itemNameController.text);
              },
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: const Center(
                    child: Text("Pay",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white))),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error is on this line inside `onTap method: model.payment(amountController.text, itemNameController.text);`

This is my view model page I want to call

```
class PaymentViewModel {
  final TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController itemNameController = TextEditingController();
  late API api;
  String? errorMessage;
  late String payFast;

  void payment(String amount, String item_name) {
    String? paymentErrorMessage = null;
    if (paymentErrorMessage != null) {
      errorMessage = paymentErrorMessage;
    } else {
      amount = amountController.text;
      item_name = itemNameController.text;
      api
          .payFastPayment(amount: amount, item_name: item_name)
          .then((createdPayment) {
        if (createdPayment == null) {
          errorMessage = "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
        } else {
          payFast = createdPayment;
        }
        print("It reaches here");
      }).catchError((error) {
        errorMessage = '${error.toString()}';
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning it before condition check in paymentModel and assigning it to a string error message
`String? paymentErrorMessage = null;`
Remove this line
Also remove this line `amount = amountController.text;`. Your method should be like this

```
void payment(String amount, String item_name) {
    
      
      item_name = itemNameController.text;
      api
          .payFastPayment(amount: amount, item_name: item_name)
          .then((createdPayment) {
        if (createdPayment == null) {
          errorMessage = "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
        } else {
          payFast = createdPayment;
        }
        print("It reaches here");
      }).catchError((error) 
        errorMessage = '${error.toString()}';
      });
    
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Kaushik Chandru, I removed the line and still get the same error.

Comment: double.parse(amount) throws an error "The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?" because amount is type String

Comment: Edited answer. Pls check

Comment: I want to know, why are you removing the amount textfield and leaving the item_name?

Comment: You are passing the amount and itemname to the method from ui. After that you again assigned the amount with the textcontroller added in the model which is null. So it was sending amount as null in the api service

Comment: Thanks man, now my errors are gone so now I want to send the values with api http call to payfast payment page using a webview and the button is not navigating, can you please help me with that.

Comment: Please post it as a new question brother :) I shall try my best to answer it

Comment: Hi @Kaushik Chandru
I hope you are well. I have posted a new question, may you please check it and see if you can help me, I will really appreciate your help man.